# how to add second order terms into the model in R?

Tags: r

My data `mydata` consists of columns of x1,x2,..,x100,y in R. But I am thinking a linear model with second order terms such as y ~ x1^2 + x2^2 + x1*x2 + ... how do I achieve that within formula or in any other way in R?

When I tried above, my model `pls` ignored all second order terms. Do I have to manually create those columns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [formula documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models) for R shows how to do this.  In short, you use `poly()`.  For example, make some quadratic data:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x + x**2 * 0.5 + rnorm(100)
```

Now fit this using a second order polynomial (i.e `x` and `x**2`) like this

```
mod <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
```

Note that this will fit an *orthogonal* polynomial, so it won't recover 1 and 0.5 as the coefficients in the generating distribution.  If for some reason you want that, use `poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE)`.  In general you don't for stability reasons, so stick with the cooked version.

There is also `polym` as in: `lm(y ~ polym(x, z, degree=2)` for a model with a full set of crossed variables, which is a bit more trouble to interpret, but that's presumably not important with hundreds of variables.

Comment: Thanks. But I have 100 predictors and I already tried poly. It's not working well with multiple predictors - I get a series of errors when I use multiple predictors with poly.

Comment: what does 'not working well' mean?

Comment: As I said, I get a series of errors.

Comment: I was asking what they were.

Comment: To automate separate `poly`s for all the variables, you could construct the formula.  This is ugly but seems to work: `forma <- eval(paste("y ~", paste(paste('poly(', names(data), ', 2)', sep=''), collapse=" + "))); mod <- lm(forma)`

Comment: Thanks. The trick you made works really well except it does not produce interaction terms. But I think I get it from what you did with string manipulation.

Comment: True, there are not interactions, but you get the idea of the string eval idea...  The 'problem' with the formula interface in R is that it expects you know a small number of variables by name.  So here we have to jump through some hoops when that's not the shape of your problem.

Comment: It's easier if you do it by `paste`ing then use `as.formula` on the resulting character string....

Answer (score 8):

Type :

```
lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + I(x1*x2) + I(x1^2) + ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But one more thing: I have 100 variables to add like what you describe. Is there any way to automatically generate those terms? Thanks again.

Comment: The I() operator tells R to treat it as math instead of treating it as an interaction and linear terms.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in principle, illustrated on a smaller dataset with only 10 predictors:

```
# Make fake data
mydata = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1100), 100))
names(mydata) = c(paste0("x", 1:10), "y")

# Form a matrix containing all predictor columns but not y
x = as.matrix(mydata[, 1:10])
# Use poly() to form all 2-way interactions and 2nd order terms
x2 = poly(x, degree = 2, raw = TRUE)
# Resave as a data frame including y
mydata2 = as.data.frame(cbind(x2, y = mydata$y))
# Fit the complete linear model
lm2 = lm(y ~ ., data = mydata2)
```

However, you have 100 predictors. In my experience, with more than 10-15 predictors, R usually cannot allocate enough memory for the matrix containing every 2-way interaction. You will get unhelpful errors or R will simply crash.

If so, consider whether you really need *all* 2-way interactions. Maybe just a subset would make sense. For instance, you could use `poly()` as above to form all 2-way interactions within one subset of x's, then again to form interactions between another subset of x's, but not have any interactions across those subsets.